# How do i calculate the broadcast address for a given subnet without any calculators?

Tags: networking, subnet

Let's say you had to answer this question and can NOT write anything down or use any calculator as 99% of the solutions I see include one of these which are not possible in this scenario:

Find the broadcast address for 192.156.68.71/21

Comment: See [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for how to calculate everything about that network.

Comment: still seems like a calculator is necessary at the least writing down the binary conversion steps.

Comment: That is how you need to do it without a calculator, but you will not get around needing to write things down. You simply do not do math quizzes without scratch paper, and it _is_ a math exercise.